# Is it possible to retrieve $|\psi_1\rangle,|\psi_2\rangle$ from their tensor product $|\psi_1\rangle\otimes|\psi_2\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, linear-algebra

Consider two quantum states$$\left| \psi_1 \right> = \alpha  \left|0\right> + \beta\left|1\right>$$ and  $$\left| \psi_2 \right> = \gamma  \left|0\right> + \delta\left|1\right>$$
Now tensor product of two states gives
$$\left| \psi \right> =  \left|\psi_1\right> \otimes \left|\psi_2\right>$$

$$\left| \psi \right> = \alpha\gamma  \left|00\right> + \alpha\delta\left|01\right> + \beta\gamma  \left|10\right> + \beta\delta\left|11\right>$$

Is it possible to factor the state $\left| \psi \right> $ and get $\left| \psi_1 \right> $ and $\left| \psi_2 \right>  $ back?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by "undo"? You could take a partial trace on one of the systems to recover the other system.

Comment: I mean can I retreive back  $\left| \psi_1 \right> $ and $\left| \psi_2 \right> $ given  $\left| \psi\right> $

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. You have two expressions for the state $x_0|00\rangle + x_1|01\rangle + x_2|10\rangle + x_3|11\rangle = \alpha\gamma  \left|00\right> + \alpha\delta\left|01\right> + \beta\gamma  \left|10\right> + \beta\delta\left|11\right>$, you just need to solve the system of equations

$$\begin{cases}
\alpha\gamma = x_0 \\
\alpha\delta = x_1 \\
\beta \gamma = x_2 \\
\beta \delta = x_3 \\
\end{cases}$$

If the system of equations has a solution, you got your answer, and as a bonus you know that your quantum system is separable (i.e., the qubits are not entangled).

Comment: +1 Might be worth mentioning that if the system of equations fails to have a solution then $x_0|00\rangle + x_1|01\rangle + x_2|10\rangle + x_3|11\rangle$ is entangled.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can factor it. For example, this is what [`cirq.sub_state_vector`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/12530f1531e5da663a6b172b1967763e08819912/cirq-core/cirq/linalg/transformations.py#L387) does and also how the amplitude displays work in Quirk.

The basic idea is that to factor out $A$ from $A \otimes B$ you look at a non-zero part of the wavefunction where B is held constant. This tells you what $A$ has to be proportional to, and you can check that the other parts of the wavefunction are consistent with this. Then you use the ratios between those pieces to derive $B$.